# angular 2 unit test case error

Tags: angular, testcase

here am stuck with one error in my angular 2 unit test case 
error is: **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./Titles class Titles_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Token translation!**

please give me solution/hint why this error comes again and again .thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the provider inside the providers

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({       
      providers: [Token translation]

    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: when i add token translation it throw [ts] 
Cannot find name 'Token'.
any error.